# How to turn off Google Lens in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google

As part of my work I search images alot on Google, i.e. using the drag and drop into the search box to get a page of similar images showing the pixel size of each image. Today when I used google (on Firefox version 104.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04) the image search is defaulting to Google Lens, which is totally unusable. Does anyone know if it is possible to turn off the lens function in Google on Firefox (or Chromium, where the old method of disabling flags no longer seems to work) and return to the standard image search.

Comment: It's a change made by Google, on Google's website. It has nothing to do with browser, so you can't change this in browser. If there is a setting to turn it off, it can be only somewhere on Google website. From a point of view of not-logged-in user, I don't see any such setting. Maybe after you log in to Google account it is possible - you have to look.

Comment: I just checked and looks like "Google Reverse Image Search" Firefox extension still makes use of the old search method, so you can probably use this. But we can't be sure for how long Google will make this possible...

Comment: Thanks Raj, yes Google Reverse Image Search is doing what I hoped for. Hopefully it will remain usable for some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install Search by Image add-on. Icon looks like a red camera. (I use Firefox.)

"Reverse image search tool, is an open source project with support for various search engines, such as Google, Bing, Yandex, Baidu and TinEye..."

Comment: Thank you. Search by Image and Reverse Image Search do seem very similar and do the trick.